# How to write $\ \sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^{k}$ or $(n+1)^{l+1}$ as $ \ \sum_{k=a}^{b} \binom{c}{d}n^{k+1}$?

Tags: combinatorics

We know $(n+1)^{l+1}=n^{l+1}+\binom{l+1}{1}n+\cdots+\binom{l+1}{l}n^l+1=\sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^k$.

**My question:**

How to write $\ \sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^{k}$ or $(n+1)^{l+1}$  as $ \ \sum_{k=a}^{b} \binom{c}{d}n^{k+1}$ ?

where $a,b,c,d$ are to be determined.

What would be in the positions of the unknowns $a,b,c,d$ ?

Comment: These sums are rather structurally different. Note, that $\binom{c}{d}$ can be factored out of the sum.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, we can write mathematically $\sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^k$ as $\sum_{k=-1}^{l} \binom{l+1}{k}n^{k+1}$. But $k=-1$ have to assume, which something odd. Is there other way of indexing keeping $n^{k+1}$ still?

Comment: If you allow the values of the summation to go outside of the range $0$ to $\ell+1$, notice that $\binom{\ell+1}{k}$ would be zero for those terms.

Comment: @JMoravitz, ok if I allow $k=-1$, then  are $\sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^k$ and $\sum_{k=-1}^{l} \binom{l+1}{k}n^{k+1}$ are equal? Can you correct this?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that if you allow the *starting index of* $k=-1$  (*$k$ takes multiple values here, not just the one*) then notice that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\ell+1}\binom{\ell+1}{k}n^k = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{\ell+1}{k}n^{k}$ or replacing $-\infty$ and $\infty$ with any finite numbers less than or equal to $0$ and greater than or equal to $\ell+1$ respectively.  The exponent on the $n$ does *not* change by doing this.

Comment: @JMoravitz, Can I write the exponent from $k$ to $k+1$ somehow? i.e., can I go from $\sum_{k=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{k}n^k $ to $\sum_{k=*}^{*} \binom{*}{*}n^{k+1}$ somehow?

Comment: Not without also changing the bottom of the binomial coefficient to also be $k+1$.  Remember... two polynomials are equal if *and only if* each corresponding coefficient is equal between the two of them.  You have a polynomial here in terms of $n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, ok thank you. Finally,  Suppose $S_k(N,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} n^{k+1}x^n$, then Can I write like $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^u=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^n}{n} \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^{u+1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n} \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^{u+1} \right)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n} \right) \left(\sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u} S_u(N,x) \right)$

Comment: Going from the second expression to the third expression makes no sense to me.  Note: $(ax+by+cz)\neq (a+b+c)(x+y+z)$., or more generally $\sum a_nb_n \neq \sum a_n \sum b_n$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Yes I also thought there in the splitting. My target is to write or input $S_k(N,x)$ in the expression $ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^u$. Can you help me here doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reiterate what I already said in the comments above.

If you have two polynomials $A(x)=a_0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots+a_n x^n$ and $B(x)=b_0x^0+b_1x^1+b_2x^2+\dots+b_mx^m$ with $a_n$ and $b_n$ both nonzero then you necessarily have $n=m$ and you necessarily have $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$.

Your summations are polynomials in terms of $n$.  It follows then that the coefficients must match as well.  Now, to be fair, you write an $n^k$ in the one expression and an $n^{k+1}$ in the other.  For that, we can rewrite things only slightly noting that $a_0x^0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+\dots+a_n x^n = a_0x^{-1+1}+a_1x^{0+1}+a_2x^{1+1}+a_3x^{2+1}+\dots+a_nx^{n-1+1}$

We get then that if you want to rewrite $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\ell+1} \binom{\ell+1}{k}n^k$ as a summation involving terms using $n^{k+1}$ instead, it *must* be and there is no other way of writing it

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\ell+1}\binom{\ell+1}{k}n^k=\sum\limits_{k=-1}^{\ell}\binom{\ell+1}{k+1}n^{k+1}$$

This, following again as a result of the theorem stated above about polynomials.

Comment: Ok, I understood this one. But my last question is different as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390831/how-to-write-or-input-the-symbol-s-kn-x-inside-the-summation-sum-n-1n?noredirect=1#comment6975870_3390831. I just want to know whether I can embedd or input $S_k(N,x)$ in the given expression and how. That is my target. Can you help me there in the final question?